# How to get all possible subset of the string in python

Tags: python

I have a case in which I want to generate all possible subset or the combination of the given string. so far I tried this:

```
def list_string(str):
   level=['']
   if len(str) <=1:
       level += str
       return level
   else:
      for item in range(len(str)):
          n_list=[]
          for item1 in level:
              n_list.append(item1 + str[item])
          level += n_list
         . return level
```

so if I call
print list_string('ab')

I get only ['', 'a', 'b', 'ab'] I am missing 'ba' in the list.
can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong.
I want to do this without using itertools or modules.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: There appears to be a SyntaxError waiting to happen on your final line.

Comment: Create a set of what you get out of list_string(str) and list_str(reverse(str))

Comment: hi Ffisegydd, is there a way to do without using itertools?

Comment: @ankit.1g itertools is fairly widely used and optimized. Any particular reason you don't want to rely on it?

Comment: You want to get the reverse substrings as well?

Comment: go and read what @Ffisegydd linked.

Comment: I wanted to try using recursion or just for loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better off using itertools but this is an interesting bit of recursion

```
def list_string(strn):
  level=[]
  def permute(prefix, suffix):
    level.append(prefix)
    if len(suffix)==0:
       return
    for i in range(len(suffix)):
      permute(prefix + suffix[i], suffix[:i]+suffix[i+1:])
  permute("",strn)
  return level

t = list_string("hey")
# ['', 'h', 'he', 'hey', 'hy', 'hye', 'e', 'eh', 'ehy', 'ey', 'eyh', 'y', 'yh', 'yhe', 'ye', 'yeh']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ios(stringinput, sub = "", i= 0):
    if i == len(stringinput):
        return [sub]
    else:
        return ios(stringinput, sub+ stringinput[i], i+1 ) + ios(stringinput, sub, i+1)



print(ios("abc"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension,

```
str= 'ab'
def subset(str)-> List[str]:
    lst= ['']
    res = ['']

    for i in range(len(str)):
        lst= [t+a for t in lst for a in str if t!=a]
        res += lst
    return res
```

this method returns the permutations:

```
['', 'a', 'b', 'ab', 'ba']
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use list comprehension:

```
def list_string(str):
  level = [x+y for x in str for y in str if len(str) > 1]
  return level
```

Then run
list_string('ab')

it should return

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```

Now work the `if` statement to your conditions.
Hope this help?

Comment: `aa` shouldn't be in the powerset of `ab`

Comment: for string 'ab', we should get [' ','a','b','ab','ba']